# Update data error using sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, sql-update

I want to update some data in a database, and I keep on getting the following error: `Java.sql.SQLException: unrecognized tokens:"Hello"`

My question is, how do I solve the issue I'm having?

You can find my code below:

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   String  value1= jTextField1.getText();
    try{

     String sql = "Update KKKB1 set Pangkat='"+value1+"' where Pangkat='"+value1+"  ";
     pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

     pst.executeUpdate();
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Updated");
     Main ad=new Main();
     ad.setVisible (true);
     dispose();

   }
```

Comment: You forgot to terminate the string literal with `'` but do consider prepared statements from duffymo's answer. Also, updating the value on rows where the `pangkat` value is already there doesn't really do anything useful.

Comment: It does if you're changing the value....two different parameters for one column.

Answer (score 1):

`PreparedStatement` escapes `String` and `Date` variables for you.

```
 String sql = "Update KKKB1 set Pangkat= ? where Pangkat=? ";
 pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
 pst.setString(1, p1);
 pst.setString(2, p2);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

I think this code is a very bad idea.  You should be closing your `Connection` & `PreparedStatement` in method scope.  You should not be mingling UI and persistence code this way.  You don't commit or rollback if the INSERT fails.